# elasticsearch match two fields

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, geolocation, match

How can I get this simple SQL query running on **elasticsearch** ?

> SELECT * FROM [mytype] WHERE a = -23.4807339 AND b = -46.60068

I'm really having troubles with it's syntax, multi-match queries doesn't work in my case, which query type should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For queries like yours `bool` filter is preferred over `and` filter. See [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/) the whole story about this suggestion and why is considered to be more efficient.

These being said, I would choose to do it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"term": {"a": -23.4807339}},
            {"term": {"b": -46.60068}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/) appears to be outdated, it says "WARNING: This article contains outdated information. We no longer recommend taking its advice" . Please if you can update your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this with the `and` filter.  For your example, something like:

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "query" : {"filtered" : {
    "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
    "filter" : {"and" : [
      "term" : {"a": -23.4807339},
      "term" : {"b": -46.60068}
    ]}
  }}
}
```

Be sure to direct the query against the correct index and type.  Note that I specified the size of the return set as 100 arbitrarily - you'd have to specify a value that fits your use case.

There's more on filtered queries [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_filtered_query.html), and more on the `and` filter [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html).

Comment: Thanks! it worked! What if i want it to return all values, is there  any way to do that without using many queries?

Comment: @ViníciusMariano If you're going to be returning large numbers of documents, your best bet is probably to look at the `scroll` functionality (which has some similarity to cursors in other database technologies).  More comprehensive documentation is here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html