# Elasticsearch match by either of two fields

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, match

Similar to [elasticsearch match two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366168/elasticsearch-match-two-fields),
I would like to execute a query in ES that uses **OR** operator

```
SELECT * FROM [mytype] WHERE title = 'some title' OR title = 'something else'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bool/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "should":[
        {
          "match":{
            "title":"some title"
          }
        },
         {
          "match":{
            "title":"something else"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mefhisto1 if the answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer as well :)